# Whenever I try to run yarn start I get this error message

Tags: react-native, yarn-lock.json

node:internal/errors:490
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error: spawn ENOTDIR
at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
at Object.spawn (node:child_process:757:9)
at spawn (/Users/ni/Desktop/WORK/RET/LEAING/ToGo/.yarn/cache/cross-spawn-npm-6.0.5-2deab6c280-f893bb0d96.zip/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:12:24)
at run (/Users/ni/Desktop/WORK/RET/LEAING/ToGo/.yarn/unplugged/expo-npm-47.0.13-9da3537782/node_modules/expo/bin/cli.js:11:12)
at Object. (/Users/ni/Desktop/WORK/RET/LEAING/ToGo/.yarn/unplugged/expo-npm-47.0.13-9da3537782/node_modules/expo/bin/cli.js:6:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
at require$$0.Module._extensions..js (/Users/ni/Desktop/WORK/RET/LEAING/ToGo//.pnp.cjs:21020:33)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
at require$$0.Module._load
(/Users/ni/Desktop/WORK/RET/LEAING/ToGo//.pnp.cjs:20839:22) {
errno: -20,
code: 'ENOTDIR',
syscall: 'spawn'
}

node version : v18.14.0
npm version: 9.4.1
yarn version: 3.4.1
expo version: WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the versioned Expo CLI (npx expo).
6.3.0
React Native version: 0.71

Thank you in advance.

If i try using npm it works (npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject),
but I want to use yarn.

Comment: if i use older react native version npm install -g expo-cli expo init AwesomeProject it works but not for the newer react version

Comment: what is the output of expo doctor?

Comment: node ver 18 is not supporting your expo version, you need to update expo sdk. What is your expo sdk version?

Comment: WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the versioned Expo CLI (npx expo).
The expected package.json path: /Users/nithishk/package.json does not exist

Comment: "expo": "^47.0.13"

Comment: I think that you can resolve this issue by downgrading node or downloading another version of node and using it as default.

Comment: still same error

Comment: what's your node version now? Can you please share expo cli's version too?

Comment: node v19.6.0 expo-cli 6.3.0

Comment: Your previous node version was v18.14.0 and now you have updated it to 19.6.0 so it won't work. You need to downgrade the node version not upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the expo CLI to a version that is compatible with Node version 18.14.0 by running the command "npx expo".

Comment: Still not working